# PHP Variable Variables

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing this comment class:

```
class Comment {

    public $id;
    public $post_id;
    public $name;
    public $email;
    public $website;
    public $body;
    public $date;
    public $ip_address;
    public $status;

    function __construct($id) {

        global $db;

        $resc = $db->query("SELECT * FROM blog_comments WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1");

        while($row = $db->fetch_assoc($resc)) {
            while ($comment = current($row)) {
                $key = key($row);
                $this->$key = $comment{$key};
                next($row);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what the query inside the constructor will return when run in the database:

[query results http://17webshop.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/Picture-2.png](http://17webshop.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/Picture-2.png)

But when I run it, this is what print_r(new Comment(1)); spits out:

```
Comment Object
(
    [id] => 1
    [post_id] => 1
    [name] => J
    [email] => j
    [website] => h
    [body] => b
    [date] => 1
    [ip_address] => :
    [status] => 1
)
```

Any ideas why I'm only getting the first character of each field?

Thanks.

Comment: Were you a Perl programmer, by any chance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

current/next is painful, and I'm not sure what's with the {} dereferencing.

Why not just:

```
$resc = $db->query("SELECT * FROM blog_comments WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1");

while($row = $db->fetch_assoc($resc)) {
    foreach($row as $key=>$value){
       $this->$key = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: you know, i had always wondered what the difference was between [] and {}. Thank you. and yes, this solution is excellent.

Comment: See mike B's answer, which is really a more concise answer.  I thought that {} would select a single char, but was too lazy to look it up.

Comment: Here's the reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr

Answer (score 6):

You want

```
$comment[$key]
```

$comment{$key} will give you the nth character of a string. Since $key itself is a string, PHP converts that to an integer 0 and you get the first char.

Comment: The integer value of those keys is 0, which is also the index of the first character of a string.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to change this line:

```
$this->$key = $comment{$key};
```

with:

```
$this->$key = $comment[$key];
```